# Define variables in csproj SDK style

Tags: wpf, .net-6.0, csproj

I have converted a WPF project to the new csproj SDK format. It shows some properties such as:

```
Company: $(Authors)
```

Where do I define the variable `$(Authors)` and similar such variables? I am building my project both locally and in Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is MSBuild specific, it does not depend on SDK project style in particular, see:

- [Define and reference properties in a project file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties?view=vs-2022)

Define a tag with the name of the property inside a `PropertyGroup`.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

   <!-- ... -->

   <PropertyGroup>
      <Authors>John Doe, Jane Doe</Authors>
   </PropertyGroup>
   
   <!-- ... -->

</Project>
```

Since you refer to a property named `Authors`, you probably mean a special property that is used for NuGet packaging, see [pack target inputs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#pack-target-inputs) and [Package properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#package-properties).

Comment: Author was just an example, maybe a poor one. The default for like version seemed to be 
$(VersionNumber)
but I couldn't for the life of me figure out where that value is suppose to be set /overridden.